# Does NullPointerException be declared in the method signature?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Nullpointerexception is considered to be a runtime exception and all runtime exceptions need not be declared in the method signature that is throwing it. But, NullPointerException gives me an compile error saying - unhandled exception! Why is it so?

```
1...void doMore(){
2...    throw new NullPointerException();
3...}
```

Line 2 shows a compile error but if any other runtime exception is thrown (like NullArgumentException) then no compile error. Is NullPointerException really unchecked exception?

Comment: Why would you want to throw a `NullPointerException` from your code to begin with?

Comment: check the docs for `Is NullPointerException really unchecked exception?`

Comment: NPE is unchecked, so there's more likely another Exception that you're failing to handle.

Comment: Which error do you get and how looks the rest of your code?

Comment: when throwing exception, make sure it has enough information- In this case IllegalArgumentException with note on what caused null may be more useful

Comment: I have just do a `public static void main(String[] args) { throw new NullPointerException(); }` small application that compiles and runs with no problems. You have something else in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: Maybe you declared `class NullPointerException extends Exception{}` somewhere.

Comment: Please post all of your code instead of pieces and provide use with the actual error you're receiving in your compiler output. We can't solve the problem with partial information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `NullPointerException` in your code anywhere, just like any other exception. However, being an unchecked exception, you don't have to declare it in the function body, or are required to handle it. So if you get a compiler error, it is not because of the `NullPointerException` but because of some other problem in the code, which you didn't post.

A method like this compiles quite fine without any errors:

```
void doSomething() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Comment: This is just a sample class with just this method and nothing else. I just replaced NullPointerException with NullArgumentException and it worked fine but did not work with NullPointerException. Is Eclipse stopping me from using it without adding throws?

Comment: No. As I said, the above method works fine, and I tested it in Eclipse. Your problem is somewhere else, but you should show the full error message and the code, to tell whats wrong.

Comment: The IDE configuration part is the issue! I tried running it in a separate project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, because NullPointerException extends [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

> A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of RuntimeException that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you don't have to since NPE is an **unchecked** exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the "doMore()" method is just to prove if NullPointerException is an unchecked exception. I don't know why would anyone need a method that throws them.

Indeed, it is unchecked. In fact, if I paste your code in a new class, using Eclipse, I get no compiler error. So I think this has to do with your IDE configuration being strict at null-relative code validations, or some other error not appearing in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can use NullPointerException as any other exception in your code but is not useful as you dont need to handle all runtime exceptions(Unchecked) in your code.

Here you are not getting error because of declaration of NullPointerException but it may be some other compilation error.

Here you can refer this example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());

    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```